# Can I make a dynamic event dispatching dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

I want to make a custom dialog, which has a button.
I want to set the button clickable, while the dialog dispatches touch events to background when its touch event is outter bound of the button.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't getting your question but if you want to make custom dialog with button which responds on click this can be possible.